# Maximum of Java HTTPUrlConnection connect timeout

Tags: java, timeout, httpurlconnection, httpconnection, connection-timeout

I need to troubleshoot why my application get Connection Timeouts, while CURL, for example, can connect to a server (my java code can too, some seconds after the first try).

I made some test codes and figured out that HTTPUrlConnection ignores when I set connect timeout more than 20 seconds, i.e., if I set to 10 seconds, the timeout occurs with 10 seconds, but if I set to 30 seconds, it occurs within 20 seconds any way.

Is there some explanation to that behavior?

Someone can advice me how to troubleshoot why am I getting connect timeout while some others applications is not?

Thank you.

Comment: have u tried to check what is set using getConnectionTimeout?

Comment: Yes, and it says 30000 milliseconds.

Comment: You can't increase the connect timeout beyond the platform default, which is normally around a minute. (And contrary to what the Javadoc says, zero is not infinity, it is the platform default.) You can only reduce it. A 20 second timeout is enormous in most circumstances.